# Update parts of TreeTable from backend

Tags: performance, primefaces, treetable

My application has a treeTable under Primfaces 6.1.1. Currently the application is using  `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("myFormId:myTreeTableId")` to update the display of the whole TreeTable.

Due to performance issue when the TreeTable contains so many nodes, I would like to update only the display of relevant **rows/nodes**. I've tried to update the display of TreeTable by row-ID like `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("myFormId:myTreeTableId_node_0_0")` where `myFormId:myTreeTableId_node_0_0` is the ID of the relevant `<tr>` as I inspected by the Developer Tool of IE 11. However, the update doesn't have any effect, the display of the relevant row on the TreeTable doesn't change although the state of the associated TreeNode in the backend has been changed.

I could only manage to update the display by table cells using the ids of `<td>` tags like  `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("myFormId:myTreeTableId:0_0:columnId")` where `0_0` is the `rowKey` of the associated TreeNode.

*Is there any way to update the display of certain rows in TreeTable including their selected state (checkbox)?*

Thanks.

Comment: If you know the rowId, you can use a server side method to find all the 'id' s of its children and add all those to the 'update' list.

Comment: I can iterate through all cells of a row and update them but state display of the relevant checkbox (checked or unchecked) doesn't get updated since checkboxes are icons in TreeTable